# Невозможно конвертировать лямбда выражение в тип 'string', потому он не является строковым типом

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Login.chtml:**

```
<tr>
    <td>@Html.Label(a => a.UserName)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBox(a => a.UserName)</td>
    <td>@Html.ValidationMessage(a => a.UserName)</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: и где тут entity framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы пользуетесь одной группой методов расширения (`Label, TextBox, ValidationMessage`), а параметры подсовываете как для группы (`LabelFor, TextBoxFor, ValidationMessageFor`).

Попробуйте такой код

```
<tr>
<td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.UserName)</td>
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.UserName)</td>
<td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.UserName)</td>
```

Comment: А ведь это действительно работает